# php private properties can be accessed outside

Tags: php, private-members

the code here outputs 20, 20, why the private property can be accessed here:

```
class myClass {
    private $a;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->a = 10;
    }

    public function printValue() {
       print "The Value is: {$this->a}\n";
    }

    public function changeValue($val, $obj = null) {
        if(is_null($obj)) {
            $this->a = $val;
        } else {
           $obj->a = $val; //why this works?
        }
     }

    public function getValue() {
      return $this->a;
     }
 }

 $obj_one = new myClass();
 $obj_two = new myClass();

 $obj_one->changeValue(20, $obj_two);
 $obj_two->changeValue($obj_two->getValue(), $obj_one);

 $obj_two->printValue();
 $obj_one->printValue();
```

any ideas?

Comment: why not? sorry thats simple OOP

Comment: You should read the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of encapsulation, it's important that the internals of a class be protected from access by other parts of code that must not know about the internals of the class. The class itself presumably knows about its internals and can access `private` properties of instances of itself just fine.

Comment: thanks, this is a good explanation to the why. my previous understanding wass private properties can not be accessed outside the object instance.

Answer (score 2):

Class can always access its own properties regardless of whether they belong to the instance itself or to another instance. This works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue.  You're not accessing the private property from outside, but inside the class and returning it.  This basic OO.

Answer (score 1):

`$obj->a = $val; //why this works?`

It works because you are passing an object of `myClass` using `$obj_two` and **inside** the class the variable `$a` can be accessed, which is perfectly fine

The restriction of accessing the private variable is enforced when you try something like:

```
$obj_two = new myClass();
echo $obj_two->a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj_one->changeValue(20, $obj_two);
$obj_two->changeValue($obj_two->getValue(), $obj_one);
```

In both lines $obj is not null so the else part is executed. During the first call value of `$this->a = 20` and during the second call when you use `$obj_two->getValue()` it retrieves the value of `$obj_two->a` which is set when you called the first function.